# Using Java API for WebSocket (JSR-356) with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-boot, jsr356

I'm new to Spring (and asking questions on stackoverflow).

I'd like to start an embedded (Tomcat) server via Spring Boot and register a JSR-356 WebSocket endpoint to it.

This is the main method:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Server.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is how the configuration looks:

```
@Configuration
public class EndpointConfig {

    @Bean
    public EchoEndpoint echoEndpoint() {
        return new EchoEndpoint();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerEndpointExporter endpointExporter() {
        return new ServerEndpointExporter();
    } 
}
```

The `EchoEndpoint` implementation is straight-forward:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/echo", configurator = SpringConfigurator.class)
public class EchoEndpoint {

    @OnMessage
    public void handleMessage(Session session, String message) throws IOException {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("echo: " + message);
    }
}
```

For the second part I've followed this blog post: https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/23/spring-framework-4-0-m1-websocket-support.

However, when I run the application I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'endpointExporter' defined in class path resource [hello/EndpointConfig.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to get javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer via ServletContext attribute
```

The exception is further caused by a `NullPointerException` in `ServerEndpointExporter`, because the `getServletContext` method on the `applicationContext` returns still `null` at this point.

Can somebody with a better understanding of Spring help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ServerEndpointExporter` makes some assumptions about the lifecycle of an application context that don't hold true when you're using Spring Boot. Specifically, it's assuming that when `setApplicationContext` is called, calling `getServletContext` on that `ApplicationContext` will return a non-null value.

You can work around the problem by replacing:

```java
@Bean
public ServerEndpointExporter endpointExporter() {
    return new ServerEndpointExporter();
}
```

With:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextAware endpointExporterInitializer(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    return new ServletContextAware() {

        @Override
        public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
            ServerEndpointExporter serverEndpointExporter = new ServerEndpointExporter();
            serverEndpointExporter.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
            try {
                serverEndpointExporter.afterPropertiesSet();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }               
        }           
    };
}
```

This defers the processing until the servlet context is available.

**Update**: You may like to watch [SPR-12109](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12109). Once it's fixed the workaround described above should no longer be necessary.

Comment: in 2018, the workaround is no more needed, but the question helped a lot. I could not find a complete example anywhere else .. cheers!!!

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.1.0.RELEASE with Java 11 and Tomcat 9 deploying WAR into tomcat webapp and still see the same error.